# How to find radius of drawn shape in MKMapView

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am stuck with an issue,

I have drawn a shape in map view and even get the center coordinate, the thing which is left to be found is the radius from the center coordinate.
if anyone could help me out.

This is the shape I have drawn, the annotation is the center point, Need to find the radius and then draw a circle on it

Here is the image : 
[image]

Comment: You could iterate through the coordinates that make up your drawn shape and calculate, for each one, the distance from your centre point. Use the largest distance as the radius and draw your circle.

Answer (score 0):

The above issue is resolved, now i need to find the difference in space between circle border and polygon border so that when my server returns data i can only show pins on the polygon.

Here is the image :- 
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/tezWr.png

Comment: I think the better approach is to request server to return pins that are only within the polygon